# How to simply get form data from Index page to Index class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created a Razor Web app and scaffolded Identity into my project as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

As shown in the code below, I have a form on the Home page that shows if you're not logged in, and I need to get that form data into a method so that I can process it (it involves the google-maps api, but I've figured that part out already)

1. I've tried creating a new Model (TestUser) describing the data I want to capture and using that as the model for this page, then creating a method in the Index.cshtml.cs page that Binds the form data to that model and writes the data to Debug - but nothing shows up and further tests (putting a breakpoint inside that method) shows that it never even calls that method
2. I've tried using a HTML POST form, but I can't figure out what the c# code should look like to process that POST

#### Attempt #1

Index.cshtml.cs

```cs
        public ActionResult CheckUser([Bind("Email", "Postcode")] TestUser user)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.Email);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.Postcode);
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```html
            <form asp-action="CheckUser">
                <label for="Email" >Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                <label for="Postcode" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="Postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
```

#### Attempt #2

Index.cshtml.cs

```cs
???
```

Index.cshtml

```html
            <form method="post">
                <label for="Email" >Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                <label for="Postcode" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="Postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
```

For the first Attempt, I was expecting it to write the Email and Postcode to Debug, but nothing showed up.

I couldn't figure out HTML POST forms well enough to try the second attempt.

The end goal is to take that info from the form on the Home page and do something with it (for example, write it to Debug)

Comment: don't you also need name="Email" and name="Postcode"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your main issue is that your inputs don't have `name` attributes. While you could just add a `name` attribute to them, it's preferable to use `asp-for` to invoke the taghelpers that among other things handle generating the right name for binding for you.

```
<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

The `id` and `type` attributes will also be filled by the helper.

Aside from that, don't use `Bind`. It's a [bad idea for a number of different reasons](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/). Instead, use a view model, and if all you want to allow to be edited is `Email` and `PostalCode`, then only add those properties to your view model class. After post, map the values from the posted view model onto an instance of your entity (new if creating, pulled fresh from the database if editing).

Comment: I used your second idea (I think) and created a new set of Razor pages for my existent TestUser Model. If I'm correct, the new pages generated act as both the views and the controller. I then had code in the home page's html redirect you to one of these views if you're not logged in. It's a shoddy solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be then put those in include list saying

```
    public ActionResult CheckUser([Bind(Include = "Email, Postcode")] TestUser user)
    {
```